# Use upright font (no italics) with svjour3 (Springer)

Tags: amsmath, theorems, document-classes, italic

I cannot find how to do that automatically for all the theorems in my latex document with the class svjour3 (provided by Springer). I use amsmath too in my document.

Comment: Did you check with Springer if such a change is ok in the first place?

Comment: You think italics are mandatory ?

Comment: I don't know, i never published with Springer. You should check with them.

Comment: Anyway, is it possible ?

Comment: It is certainly possible.

Comment: Just define a new set of theorem-like environments: `\spnewtheorem{utheorem}{Theorem}{\bfseries}{\rmfamily}`

Comment: @egreg Wanna write up an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B Done

Answer (score 2):

With `svjour` you should use `\spnewtheorem`, rather than `\newtheorem`; you can define a new series of environments with

```
\spnewtheorem{utheorem}{Theorem}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\normalfont}
```

and similarly for other environments. The syntax of `\spnewtheorem` is

```
\spnewtheorem{env_nam}{caption}[within]{cap_font}{body_font}
\spnewtheorem{env_nam}[numbered_like]{caption}{cap_font}{body_font}
\spnewtheorem*{env_nam}{caption}{cap_font}{body_font}
```

So, if you want theorems to be numbered within sections and propositions to share the counter for theorems, you do

```
\spnewtheorem{utheorem} % environment name
  {Theorem}             % label
  [section]             % numbered within
  {\normalfont\bfseries}% label font
  {\normalfont}         % body font

\spnewtheorem{uprop}    % environment name
  [utheorem]            % numbered like
  {Proposition}         % label
  {\normalfont\bfseries}% label font
  {\normalfont}         % body font
```

(the comments are optional, just for better clarity).

`\spnewtheorem*` defines a numberless theorem-like environment.

Comment: merci beaucoup :-)